# Printing large files using perl CGI

Tags: perl

I need to print text on browser with my perl CGI application, the file i need to print can be of large size 30 - 100MB or  more.
I have the following code

```
    $lns=$_[0];
    open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $lns) or die "Could not open file '$lns' $!";
    while (my $l = <$fh>) {
        chomp $l;
        print "<br>$l";

     }
```

Which works well but it's very slow displaying large file, 30 MB file take up 15 minutes.
Is there a way to speed it up?
To clarify, file start to be displayed immediately but browser keep loading and displaying new lines for 10 - 15 minutes for 30 - 40 MB file.
the file is static and is not being modified.

Comment: Can you explain where it is slow? You could turn off buffering with `$|=1`, then the user in front of the browser would at least see stuff sooner. But that's not going to make it any faster.

Comment: the printing of line on the browser, to display the whole file 30 MB took 15 minute or maybe more. Basically the browser keep loading new lines for several minutes. Just wondering if there is a way to speed up the process or the only way will be to split the file in multiple pages or similar (which I wished to avoid)

Comment: Is the text truly dynamic?

Comment: What do you mean with the text truly dynamic? The input file is fixed text file, it won't change and won't be modified, if this was your question

Comment: I have not done any testing so I can't say if this will help much, but I'd try reading the file in chunks (maybe 1MB at a time) instead of line-by-line.  You'd need to use a regex to substitute the `\n` with `<br>` instead of using chomp.

Comment: So, what is the point of outputting it using CGI?

Comment: @SinanÜnür adding HTML `<br>`s it seems. Ron makes a good point suggesting chunked reading.

Comment: @simbabque No, adding `<br>`s is a one time operation. It does not need to be repeated for every request. And, the reading in chunks thing can be funky depending on what's going on with encodings.

Comment: Another option would be slurp the whole file and wrap it in `<pre>...</pre>` tag.

Comment: @RonBergin It is not a good idea to increase the memory footprint of CGI programs like that. It is a sure fire way to cripple a server with only a few visitors.

Comment: Hmm, that's true, unless the file is also used for other purposes that don't need the `<br>`s. In that case simply making a copy and replacing once would be sufficient.

Comment: This is contrary to good web design. No one is going to read a 30MB document all the way through so there's no point in displaying it. You need to allow the user to select a part of the document that they're interested in and send just that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments:

> The input file is fixed text file, it won't change and won't be modified

Therefore, you should do the conversion from the input to the output format **once** and redirect visitors to the location of the already generated output file. Let the server software handle sending it.

Also, check how well the same browser deals with displaying the same content when it is loaded from the local file system.

Keep in mind that you seem not to be sending `text/plain` content. For some reason, you are sending `text/html` and inserting line breaks manually. Let's say each line is 512 bytes. For a 40 MB file, that's more than 80,000 nodes in the DOM. If each line is 80 bytes, we are talking about almost 525,000 nodes in the DOM. That may cause issues with the browser.

To test this, I created a file using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $CHARS_PER_LINE = 72;
my $text = 'x' x $CHARS_PER_LINE;

for my $i (1 .. 40 * 1024 * 1024 / $CHARS_PER_LINE) {
    print "<br>$text\n";
}
```

This gave me the following file:

```
$ ls -lh ytt.html
-rw-r--r--  1 abc abc    43M Nov 18 13:31 ytt.html
```

Then, I loaded this document in Firefox from the SSD on my [MacBook Pro with 16GB memory](https://www.nu42.com/2013/02/mid-2010-macbook-pro-71-with-16-gb-ddr3.html). This caused CPU usage to spike to 100% for almost 30 seconds, caused Firefox to become unresponsive, and caused Firefox to allocate an extra 2.5GB memory. Now, if the computer you are using does not have a lot of spare memory, it would have to swap to disk. In that case, I can easily envision scenarios that cause serious usability issues.

Opening the same file as plain text was less painful but not great either.

A question you have to answer is whether there is any good reason for this document to be displayed in the browser, or should it be just available as a download?

In any case, you should also ensure that your web server software applies compression to text files so you can serve this file using about 10% of the bandwidth that would be required otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, you suggest i convert my text file in some html fil formatted and have the browser open that one directly?

Comment: ok this is an interesting approach, will give it a try and see how it goes

Comment: Dont't forget: ***Also, check how well the same browser deals with displaying the same content when it is loaded from the local file system.***

Comment: will try that too thought I want to hope that the network is not the bottleneck, at leas not for 30 MB, access is just from local company network

Comment: I am not talking about the network being the bottleneck. I am talking about whether a browser is able to display this file with no problems. ***local file system*** means the disk drive of the computer on which you are running the browser.

Comment: well the file is really a plain text, so I don't expect any issue but i'll try

Comment: You are not serving the file as plain text, i.e. with the `text/plain` content type. You are serving it as `text/html` -- otherwise, inserting the `<br>` makes no sense. See updates to my answer.

Comment: I get way lower memory and cpu usage opening the file locally, but anyway redirect to an html  file generated from the original one does the trick, opening times went from several minutes to 1 minute or less. Have to find a way to display it properly withing my application  rather than just open a new page but that's a different problem